# Making the suggested results using Search Autocomplete in Drupal as links

Tags: search, drupal-6

I am using `Drupal 6` and currently installed the module `Search Autocomplete`. I did not touch any of the codes which enables the autocomplete module to work and I wonder if there's a way to make the suggested results in the autocomplete search as links to each specific node without editing any lines of codes. Is this possible? If yes then where would I start? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried http://drupal.org/project/views_search
You could create a view that outputs the results as links for your search results.

Or you could do http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr_views with acquia solr hosting

Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: this is the link the acquia solr hosting http://www.acquia.com/products-services/acquia-network/cloud-services/acquia-search